# Usage of second sentence posed as a question

Tags: grammar, sentence-patterns

"He might wait till Christmas to gorge on rum cake.

Why should you?"

This is an ad copy for an online food delivery site. 
I want to know if the second line - Why should you?, is grammatically correct? Please help.

Answer (score 2):

It's fine. One can omit repeated material that is implied or understood. Unnecessary repetition is tedious and annoys the reader.

*He* might wait till Christmas to gorge on rum cake. Why should *you* [wait till Christmas to gorge on rum cake]?

He asked me if I liked music. Did he ask you?

More elaborate example:

I like eating chocolate at night while wearing a hat and coat. Do you?

Comment: Thank you so much for clarifying.